# Reading czech characters from a txt file using PHP

Tags: php, file, utf-8, character-encoding, character

I’m having issues with reading Czech characters from a txt file.

I want to read .txt files containing categories line by line. With general languages I have no issue. I can read the txt file line by line and copy the categories that I want in an array.

But as soon as I want to read a txt file that contains categories in the Czech language I get problems processing the output of my code. The Czech specific characters are coming out rubbish even though the text file is showing the characters correctly.

As an example:
The letters ě, č, ů or ř are all outputed as a square or as st\u001b or other rubish, depending on the way I read the file.

Origionally I use the fgets function to read a line from the text file.

But as this didn’t return the correct characters I started testing with adding utf8_encode but whilst that changed some characters it still didn’t restore all the characters.

Then I started experimenting with mb_detect_encoding combined with mb_convert_encoding and later read somewhere that fgets could sometimes return incorrect characters so I started testing with file_get_contents. This also didn’t solve the issue.

I assume the main issue is with the way I’m reading the txt file as the output from the fgets and file_get_contents functions are garbled from the start.

Can anyone tell me how to read a text file with Czech characters correctly?

Thanks In advance.

Comment: `\u001` doesn't show up from nowhere, you must have specific code that generates it (it appears to be a JavaScript/JSON unicode entity). Also, don't try functions blindly. Why `utf8_encode()`? Latin-1 can't even store Czech characters!

Comment: The reason for trying blindly is that I was working on this issue for two weeks now. Looked all over Internet for a solution but most articles where about loading html pages and not txt files. So I was in a fase of trying all options I could think of :-). Coincidentally I found the issue was in the txt file and nog in the code I used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oké I found the solution myself. Just for the case someone else runs into this issue, the txt file was in the wrong coding. The file was in the "UCS-2 Little Endian" coding. After loading the file in Notepad++ I could encode it to the UTF-8 format and that solved the problem.